# SQL Server 2012 Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server error says Invalid object name what should I do now.Database name is Sample and table name is tblEmployee contains some column and id column is identity column

[image]

Comment: You're pointed to the MASTER database.  Either USE SAMPLE, or select Sample from the drop-down

Comment: it works after change database pointer..........thanks

Comment: Never had a doubt  :)

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
use Sample;
```

Before your insert statement